# How does mod_reqtimeout calculate data rate?

Tags: apache-2.2

The [reqtimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html) module has a setting for mimimal data-rate, which looks (inlucing default comment) like this for the body:

```
# Wait max 10 seconds for the first byte of the request body (if any)
# From then, require a minimum data rate of 500 bytes/s
RequestReadTimeout body=10,minrate=500
```

How is this datarate calculated? How much leniency does a client have if for instance it is experiencing a small hickup?
For instance, when doing a somewhat larg-ish request (say posting a file?) I can imagine that while overall the speed will be much higher then that, at a certain point there could be a reason that rate isn't met. Is it measured per second? or some sort of shifting window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the docs are actually clear on this:
From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html

> Allow at least 10 seconds to receive the request body. If the client sends data, increase the timeout by 1 second for every 1000 bytes received, with no upper limit for the timeout (exept for the limit given indirectly by LimitRequestBody):

From that we can see that for each "minrate" amount of bytes, we get an extra second. So the 'rate' is not "speed" (for wich you should define a window, etc).

You have an initial `body` seconds, and that is your first window, if you want to talk in those terms. Every `minrate` amount of bytes adds one second, so as long as you have time, you can drop speed for a bit.